# Unix Sockets example, compiler can't find headers

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compilation, libraries

**Platform: Odroid N2 running Ubuntu**

I am trying to compile and link the client and listener from the Unix sockets example here - https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-networking ; code is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "sock.h"

void report(const char* msg, int terminate) {
  perror(msg);
  if (terminate) exit(-1); /* failure */
}

int main() {
  int fd = socket(AF_INET,     /* network versus AF_LOCAL */
                  SOCK_STREAM, /* reliable, bidirectional, arbitrary payload size */
                  0);          /* system picks underlying protocol (TCP) */
  if (fd < 0) report("socket", 1); /* terminate */

  /* bind the server's local address in memory */
  struct sockaddr_in saddr;
  memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));          /* clear the bytes */
  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* versus AF_LOCAL */
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* host-to-network endian */
  saddr.sin_port = htons(PortNumber);        /* for listening */

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0)
    report("bind", 1); /* terminate */

  /* listen to the socket */
  if (listen(fd, MaxConnects) < 0) /* listen for clients, up to MaxConnects */
    report("listen", 1); /* terminate */

  fprintf(stderr, "Listening on port %i for clients...\n", PortNumber);
  /* a server traditionally listens indefinitely */
  while (1) {
    struct sockaddr_in caddr; /* client address */
    int len = sizeof(caddr);  /* address length could change */

    int client_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &caddr, &len);  /* accept blocks */
    if (client_fd < 0) {
      report("accept", 0); /* don't terminate, though there's a problem */
      continue;
    }

    /* read from client */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ConversationLen; i++) {
      char buffer[BuffSize + 1];
      memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
      int count = read(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
      if (count > 0) {
        puts(buffer);
        write(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); /* echo as confirmation */
      }
    }
    close(client_fd); /* break connection */
  }  /* while(1) */
  return 0;
}
```

I thought the necessary header files should be on the system, because as an exercise, I rebuilt linux from source (using the native compile procedure) here - https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-n2/software/building_kernel, and it compiled, linked and will boot. However, I am missing something fundamental when trying to compile the sockets examples: when I use

`gcc listener.c -o listener`
... it gives:

```
defs.h: No such file or directory
#include <defs.h>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

I have installed build-essential and linux-libc-dev. Same result.
As an answer to questions like mine, I find guidance to install the kernel headers. I tried this as follows:

- When I use `uname -r`, I get:  4.9.196+
- When I try to install the header files specific to that release, as in:
  `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`    ... I get:
  `E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.196`
- The linux source and all its include files are in /home/odroid/linux; so I thought I could just include this library by doing this:
  `gcc -I/home/odroid/linux/include listener.c -o listener`

However, when I do that, it gives a lot of errors due to conflicting types, and still doesn't find defs.h .

My PATH:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

What am I missing?

Comment: `it gives`  - sholdn't it give way more? Like which header includes `defs.h`?

Comment: Kamil - thanks, your simple question solved it!  I had been making the silly assumption that defs.h was a kernel header.  It is not!  It is included in the example down in a subdirectory that I had not noticed. I just had to to copy the defs.h file into the directory where the source is, and change this - ```#include <defs.h>``` to this - ```#include "defs.h"``` - and it compiles. (I am sure there is a more correct way to reference the header file in the subdirectory, but for now I will use this, until I learn the proper way.)

Comment: What you meant by "kernel header" is probably a header that is available at the standard system search paths. You can just `#include "subdirectory/defs.h"` or add the subdirectory to the include search paths `gcc -I subdirectory`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that defs.h is not a kernel header. It is included in the example; see comment above.